# Change HTML Input to only be able to type numbers

Tags: html, input

I am building a PHP webpage that takes numbers as inputs and calculates the total change.

Even tho the input will only accept numbers and '.' I dont want anyone to be able to type anything other then "1-9, '.'" How would I do this. Here is the code

```html
<h1 id="title">Transaction Calculator</h1>
<form action="calculatechange.php" method="post">
  <label for="total_cost" id="label1">Total Cost of Transaction</label>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" required>
  <br><br>
  <label for="amount_provided" id="label2">Total Amount of Money Provided</label>
  <input type="number" step="0.01" name="amount_provided" id="amount_provided" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate Change" id="changebutton">
</form>
```

Comment: Using `type="number"` does that. I can't type anything else into the input.

Comment: Only 1-9? So they can't type `10` or `.01`? I think you mean 0-9.

Comment: If you want to prevent negative numbers, use `min="0"`

Comment: [Consider this](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/) before using `type="number"` as suggested by @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar I do mean 0-9. But I am able to type letters in there, why cant you but I can?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @prinkpan To be fair, it's already in their code, I wasn't really suggesting it. I was just saying that it should already do what they want.

Comment: @Barmar Newest version of fire fox. Confused why its not working

Comment: Confirmed, FF only checks when you submit, it doesn't prevent typing. But `inputmode="decimal"` should work, as recommended in the link that @prinkpan gave.

Comment: @Barmar ```inputmode="decimal"``` did not work either. This is the solution I found ```oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');"```

Comment: @GalacticLux If you found a solution you should post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you've found (such as below) works in certain extent

```
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1').replace(/^0[^.]/, '0');"
step="0.01" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" required
>
```

However, it will break the down-arrow function (aka spinner) after you reach 0, and then the system fails to go to -0.01, -0.02, -0.03.....

Another method, which will not break the down-arrow/spinner function of the input box, is by using onkeypress event of JavaScript to detect the user's input. Something like:

```
 onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
```

So the code is:

```
<h1 id="title">Transaction Calculator</h1>
<form action="calculatechange.php" method="post">
  <label for="total_cost" id="label1">Total Cost of Transaction</label>
  <input type="number"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" step="0.01" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" required>
  <br><br>
  <label for="amount_provided" id="label2">Total Amount of Money Provided</label>
  <input type="number"   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" step="0.01" name="amount_provided" id="amount_provided" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate Change" id="changebutton">
</form>


<script>

function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if ( (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57) && charCode!=47  )
            return false;
 
         return true;
      }

</script>
```